# Unity3D JavaScript/.NET code throwing compilation error with a List-thingy

Tags: unity, javascript, unityscript

So, I do this:

```
var intlist:List.<System.Int32>;
intlist.Add(1);
```

And where I say intlist.Add(1) I get:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Weird, huh? Apparently, the error is .NET related and List is a .NET thing. So, please clarify the problem. Thank you.

EDIT:

The "add comment" button isn't working, so I will respond in the form of an edit. No, I can't use a JavaScript array because for whatever reason it screws up in the context of my code and the Unity people say I shouldn't use them. The syntax I am using is correct (as far as I know) in JavaScript, but I don't know if it would be null or not. Obviously, it starts out empty. That's sort of the point.

EDIT 2:

It looks like I can't accept answers either. Thanks to the both of you. It turns out I did need to call the constructor, despite some rather strange syntax errors I was getting earlier. Blowing your magic fairy dust on it made the problem go away.

Comment: i extended my answer, this should provide you with a solution. Nevertheless you should read up on some additional resources. The articel i linked is a good startign point. In generell ArrayList and Hashtables are better in unity, as they are wrapped by the UnityScript implementation.

Comment: Also the reason you are unable to comment yet is due to your karma score called Reputation. Accepting answers and participating in the site will gain you rep points and you can comment on other posts at 50 rep points. I added an answer myself just to encapsulate what you need

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the list you are adding to is still null. In c# you would need to do something along `var intList=new List<System.Int32>` but I am not totally sure with JS.

I am more used to the array as a list element in JS, maybe take a look at [this article](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/arrays.shtml)

```
var intlist=new Array() //1) regular array. Pass an optional integer argument to control array's size.
intlist[0]=1;
```

Edit regarding your edit:

Just to clarify: There is a huge difference between a list beeing **null** or **empty**.
When you are creating your var, you basically just tell the code that you want to use a list somewhere. This object ist still *null*, which means there is no memory allocated for it. You need to **create the object** (again in C#) usally by using the *constructor*. 
The list constructor will yield you an *empty* (but no longer *null*) list.
To this list you may add objects.

This is your error, accoidng to [this article about collections in unity](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Which_Kind_Of_Array_Or_Collection_Should_I_Use?) your syntax is not wrong, but it is incomplete.
See this snipped from the article:

```
var myList : List.<Type> = new List.<Type>();  // declaration
var someNumbers = new List.<int>();            // a real-world example of declaring a List of 'ints'
var enemies = new List.<GameObject>();         // a real-world example of declaring a List of 'GameObjects'
myList.Add(theItem);                           // add an item to the end of the List
myList[i] = newItem;                           // change the value in the List at position i
var thisItem = List[i];                        // retrieve the item at position i
myList.RemoveAt(i);                            // remove the item from position i
```

As you notice you need to initalize the list first via *constructor*, by calling it with the *new* keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I got this fully functioning in Unity on an empty game object, you need to make sure you make the list with the new statement and also ensure you have the imports correctly defined.

```
#pragma strict
import System.Collections.Generic;
import System.Linq;

function Start () {
    var intlist : List.< System.Int32 > = new List.< System.Int32 >() ;
    intlist.Add(42);
    Debug.Log(intlist[0] ); //Outputs 42
}
```